# How to run function on keypress while in Background?

Tags: python, function, background, keypress

I've been struggling with this for awhile, so I thought I'd ask here. I'm trying to get

```
def pause():
global pid, p
pid = [pid]
p = psutil.Process(pid)
p.suspend()
```

bound to the 'end' key, which can be changed with a variable. How can I bind it to a keypress while it also not being in focus on the screen.
Sorry if this is confusing, I mean like having the script running behind another application, but still registering the keypress.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use [pyHook](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/) to accomplish this. It catches system level mouse and keyboard inputs.

Here is a simple example

```
from pyHook import HookManager
from win32gui import PumpMessages, PostQuitMessage

class Keystroke_Watcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hm = HookManager()
        self.hm.KeyDown = self.on_keyboard_event
        self.hm.HookKeyboard()


    def on_keyboard_event(self, event):
        try:
            if event.KeyID  == 35: # end is keycode 35
                self.pause()
        finally:
            return True

    def pause():
        global pid, p
        pid = [pid]
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        p.suspend()

    def shutdown(self):
        PostQuitMessage(0)
        self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()


watcher = Keystroke_Watcher()
PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it out when I get home. How would I go about binding a different key to a different function? Like 'end' for one function and 'home' for another?

Comment: Update on my previous question: I'm assuming I can add another 'if' statement and it'll work, correct?

Comment: You just need to lookup the keycodes associated with those keys. Make sure whatever function you bind to doesn't delay for too long. If the code doesn't return True the keystroke is blocked

Comment: @MaxFieschko If this answered your question please feel free to accept it

Comment: My bad, I haven't been able to get PyHook installed but that's not your fault - accepting now.

Comment: you can download the whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and then use pip to install it